# "Дух Сообщества"/Community поднимает не только вопросы без ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дух-сообщества

Согласно описанию участника [«Дух сообщества»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0?tab=profile):

> Обычно я:
>
> - случайным образом раз в час поднимаю старые вопросы без ответов в общем списке для того, чтобы они получили чуточку дополнительного внимания;
> - ...

Однако, по моим наблюдениям, Дух сообщества поднимает и старые вопросы, уже имеющие ответ (и даже не один). Пример такого вопроса: [Выделение и удаление памяти в JNI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11296/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-jni). Под другие пункты деятельности Духа сообщества, насколько я вижу, в данном вопросе ничего не подпадает.

Возможно это так и задумано, но тогда это противоречит описанию данного участника, следовательно - нужно или исправить описание, либо исправить функциональность.

Comment: Скорее всего, здесь просто наблюдается расхождение в формулировках: "вопросы без ответов" на самом деле не вопросы, на которые не дали ответы, а вопросы, на которые не дали полезных ответов. А полезные ответы - это принятые ответы или ответы с положительной суммой голосов. Еще про расхождения формулировок см. в [этом ответе](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808/5079)

Comment: Не прошло и года, исправлено! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно немного изменить формулировку описания:

> > ...поднимаю старые вопросы без принятых ответов и ответов с положительной суммой голосов...

Comment: Отличный вариант! Небольшая правка: не _"ответов с положительной суммой голосов"_, а _"ответов с положительным рейтингом"_, [согласно глоссарию перевода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487/).

Comment: Я за этот вариант + ссылка на этот или новый вопрос.

Comment: Предлагаю исправить на «рейтинг» и отправлять в продакшен )

Comment: Собственно, исправил на рейтинг и применил ))

Answer (score 6):

Дух сообщества поднимает «неотвеченные вопросы».

Джефф Этвуд в статье [OK, Now Define "Answered"](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) дает следующее определение:

> - Answered questions have at least one answer with one upvote (or accepted)
> - Unanswered questions have no answers with upvotes (or accepted)

То есть, чтобы вопрос считался системой отвеченным, необходимо чтобы

- Или был принятый автором вопроса ответ
- Или был хотя бы один ответ с рейтингом 1 или выше.

Вопрос «Выделение и удаление памяти в JNI» не соответствует ни одному из критериев. В нем два ответа, на одном 0, на другом -1.

Comment: @insolor, не, ответ зря приняли, т.к. это объясняет такое поведение только для тех, кто прочитал ответ. Т.е. исходная проблема (не соответствие написанного и ожидаемого)  так и не решена. Надо либо как-то переформулировать описание (что-то типа "поднимаю старые вопросы без полезных ответов") либо сделать "вопросы без ответов" ссылкой, например, на этот вопрос

Comment: @BOPOH: автор вопроса не получит уведомление о вашем комментарии. Предлагаю комментировать вопрос. Кстати, я согласен, что описание нужно переформулировать. И нам нужен текст в справке, на мете или в описании метки, дающий определение отвеченного и неотвеченного вопроса.

Comment: вопросы же такого плана подразумевают "ответ - возможное решение"? Т.е. можно предложить мои два варианта как два ответа, а сообщество выберет тот, который нравится больше (или предложит свои)? Тогда и автор заметит мои комменты

Comment: @BOPOH: предлагайте, конечно.

Answer (score 3):

Так же можно использовать и такую формулировку.

> ... поднимаю старые неотвеченные вопросы...

Answer (score 3):

Сегодня Дух поднял [древний вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267429/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). У вопроса есть ответ с рейтингом `1`. Допускаю, что этот `+1` мог появиться уже после поднятия вопроса, но узнать это рядовому пользователю не представляется возможным. Это к вопросу нет ли тут какого-то бага в алгоритме Духа. И не стоило бы добавить в историю ещё и изменение по голосам.

При этом, сам вопрос имеет 0 голосов, и автор вопроса не появлялся на сайте с момента задания вопроса (>2.5 лет). По моему мнению, такие вопросы нет смысла поднимать, т.к. они никого не заинтересовали, даже автора в должной степени.

Comment: На ответе два голоса за, один дан вчера, второй - только что. Считайте что отвечавший наконец получил свою заслуженную награду :)

Comment: @PashaPash речь-то не об отвечавшем, а о смысле поднятия таких вопросов Духом.

Comment: смысл - чтобы автор ответа получил заслуженный плюс. или минус.

Comment: @PashaPash так автор ответа уже имел `+1` на момент поднятия, по Вашим же словам. Или это было ещё не `заслуженный плюс`?

Comment: нет, на момент поднятия был 0. +1 он получил сразу после поднятия - кто-то плюсанул с главной.

Comment: @PashaPash, понял. Ввело в заблуждение Ваше `один дан вчера` и отметка у вопроса `обновлен сегодня`. Разные точки отсчета времени.

Comment: В этом случае стоило задать новый вопрос, а не давать ответ на старый.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в формулировку описания ссылку, описывающую что значит "вопросы без ответов" (например, на этот вопрос):

> > ...поднимаю старые вопросы [без ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122)...

Answer (score -1):

Можно немного изменить формулировку описания:

> > ...поднимаю старые вопросы без полезных ответов...

Answer (score -3):

Какой смысл в поднятии вопросов с вариантами ответов 3-х летней давности? Даже если ответы бесполезные. Если автор вопроса зарегистрировался однажды ради этого одного вопроса и больше никогда не появлялся, неужели он одумается, вернется и примет правильный ответ? :) Я уже молчу про полезность и актуальность новых ответов для автора.

Comment: Для конкретного автора профит может и отсутствует, но другим пользователям это может быть полезно

Comment: насколько я знаю, вопросы поднимаются только в том случае, если для них нет ответов хотя бы с 1 голосом за. это общий критерий неотвеченности на сайте. [судя по data.so](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/360106/), многим вопросам приходится полежать несколько лет, и только потом получить ответ - процент отвеченных вырастает до 85 только через ~30 месяцев.

Comment: Я однажды увидел такой вопрос, не заметил что он старый и [ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425121/181472). В процессе заинтересовался темой, потом неоднократно возвращался и что-то добавлял, либо исправлял ошибки. В итоге сам очень многое узнал. Кстати, автор вернулся и принял ответ =)