# Лучшие вопросы - Stack Overflow

Tags: поддержка

Кто ставит вопросы в Лучшие? Может быть такое, что кто отвечает на вопросы, и сами их ставят в лучшие?

Comment: нет, здесь скорее _трудности перевода_ :-)

Comment: По голосам (и просмотрам?) сами всплывают?

Comment: @alexolut вопросы определённо связаны, но это не дубликат. Там предложение поменять строки, здесь вопрос о фунационале сайта )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну, ок. Хотя в предложенном дубликате суть тоже раскрывается об обновлениях.

Comment: Речь о "Top new questions this week:", которые по почте приходят?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В оригинале это "Top Questions". По сути, последние N активных вопросов. Под активностью понимается в частности:

- появление вопроса;
- появление ответа к вопросу;
- редактирование вопроса или ответа;
- объявление конкурса для вопроса;
- [поднятие Духом сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1122/181472);
- возможно, что-то ещё ...

Вероятно, прилагательное "лучшие", действительно, не совсем подходящее тут слово. Можно использовать слово "топ" явно.

Кстати, уже полгода как висит [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3126/176217) по данной теме.

Comment: Да, "лучшие" тут не годится, это точно. Кстати, только сейчас обратил внимание на этот заголовок. А может эту надпись просто убрать, раз ничего кроме недоумения (у тех, кто ее замечает) она не вызывает.