# Почему Дух сообщества занимается некромантией?

Tags: обсуждение, дух-сообщества

Зачем он поднимает очень старые вопросы?

Например, вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231009/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) вопрос всплыл на главную.

Ок, нету принятого ответа... Однако, на мой взгляд, его не имеет смысла поднимать, так как вопрос никогда не получит принятый ответ, так как автор давно не сидит на сайте, судя по активности.

Comment: Дух сообщества не может гадать, придёт автор или нет -- просто поднимает.

Comment: @AK А на сколько он настраиваемый? Просто, нельзя ли его научить пинговать авторов вопроса и просить сделать принятие. Еще можно ограничить дату поднятия. Просто, если он ну очень старый, то скорее всего он не актуальный.

Comment: @iluxa1810, зачем что-то делать, если и так работает?

Comment: Голосуйте за закрытие, удаление вопроса, минусуйте или плюсуйте вопрос или ответы. И тогда дух перестанет его поднимать, он поднимает только те вопросы, по ему которым не понятно хорошие они или плохие

Comment: Так там же по числу голосов, а не по принятости ответа.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса (но это не точно): ["Дух Сообщества"/Community поднимает не только вопросы без ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122/%d0%94%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-community-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Оффтоп: Когда уже починят перевод автокомментария при отметке вопроса как дубликат?)

Answer (score 7):

Затем, что неотвеченные вопросы - это плохо. Либо на них надо ответить, либо их надо закрыть.

Автор вопроса не нужен. Насколько я помню, достаточно хотя бы одного плюса у хотя бы одного ответа, чтобы вопрос перестал подниматься Духом.

Answer (score 4):

Поднятие старых вопросов - давняя тема для обсуждений.

Недавно (ну, относительно), поведение было изменено.

Как я ответил на [Computational Science Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/20688), согласно [посту на Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378736/2452869) с января 2019 (вольный перевод):

> дух общества не может поднимать вопросы, если они уже были подняты менее чем X дней назад.

В январе, X=90 дней.

В феврале, [согласно посту Shog'a на Meta.Robotics](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1375/23685), X=120.

Таким образом, для небольших сообществ это точно перестало стать проблемой. На Computational Science где я обитаю регулярно бывает проходят недели без поднятия старых вопросов.

Для больших сообществ (Ru.StackOvervflow), даже относительно большой X будет означать, что скорее всего, поднятия вопросов будут случаться каждый день и ограничиваться тем, насколько часто день дух может поднимать вопросы. В любом случае, эти вопросы точно будут разными и не будут повторяться часто.

Исходя из того, что StackExchange это прежде всего база знаний, поднятие старых вопросов - важная и хорошая функциональность, особенно когда она настроена.